# 'TypeLoadException: Could not load type' for Entity Framework databaseInitializer in web.config

Tags: entity-framework, web-config

I am trying to set the databaseInitializer for a Entity Framework DBContext to `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`.

Using the following entry in my `web.config`:

```
<entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  <contexts>
    <context type="Domain.EVRMDBContext, EVRM">
      <databaseInitializer type="System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges, EntityFramework" />
    </context>
  </contexts>
```

I get an exception however:

```
[TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Domain.EVRMDBContext' from assembly 'EVRM'.]
--snip--
[InvalidOperationException: Failed to set database initializer of type   'System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges, EntityFramework' for DbContext type 'Domain.EVRMDBContext, EVRM' specified in the application configuration. See inner exception for details.]
```

I suspect the reference to the DBContext is incorrect (`Domain.EVRMDBContext, EVRM`). In the root of my project is a Domain package, which contains the EVRMDBContext class.

[image: My solution's contents]

Comment: Did you ever solve this? If so, do you remember how?

Comment: I am afraid not, I stopped using a database initializer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the type of the DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges as well:

```
<databaseInitializer
     type="System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`1[[Domain.EVRMDBContext, EVRM]], EntityFramework" />
```

Comment: I still get a 
[TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Domain.EVRMDBContext' from assembly 'EVRM'.]
[InvalidOperationException: Failed to set database initializer of type 'System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`1[[Domain.EVRMDBContext, EVRM]], EntityFramework' for DbContext type 'Domain.EVRMDBContext, EVRM' specified in the application configuration. See inner exception for details.]